# Right truncation and right censoring

Tags: survival, censoring, truncation

Is is possible for a survival data to be **right truncated and right censored **. If so, please leave an example for better understanding. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at the top of page 2 of http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~mlunn/lecturenotes1.pdf, which contains definitions and examples of both truncation and censoring, both left and right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is more of a abridged version. Say, the examples are in one line. Do you have any further papers or resources in your mind.